# Excel, interact with UserForms using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, user-interface, automation

I have a hundred of Excel programs that can generate different types of report. Those
programs contains UserForms which requires users login database or specify other details, before generate the report. Now, users need to enter those information manually to generates the reports.

I would like to know that is there any way I can use VBA to automate the report generation process. 
For example, I need a programs to open another workbooks, enter the username password and press enter.

I am wondering if Sendkeys function can help me to do so?

Comment: Sendkeys will help, but you should try to seperate the Userforms from the actions. That means: Instead of a button who raises an procedure which performs the actions you build something like this:
A separate program which has your report subs /functions which will be called with parameters.
These parameters can be set by your Userforms or an automate program - which one was the originator should not matter for the functions.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But it may time consuming to dig out all sub/functions and parameters to generate the reports. besides, some parameters are set in the event handler of UserForms. So, it is better if I can interact with the UserForms object directly using VBA. Is it feasible for me to do so?